# Unity Object scale with right mouse click

Tags: unity-game-engine, resize, click, zooming, mouse

Maybe someone know.

Resize (`zoom in, zoom out`) selected object in scene when right mouse is clicking.

I know what resize all object in the scene but I need change one object size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this. 
Use:

```
void OnMouseEnter(){}
void OnMouseOver(){}
void OnMouseExit(){}
```

and Use if like this:

```
 Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || Input.GetMouseButton(1)
```